# Ejabberd and in-band registration

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

eyeryone! I have a problem with ejabberd. Ejabberd mod_register config have:

```
[{access, register}]
```

When i send:

```
<body rid='1833385270' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='ddc858306087c89bb1b95f6d507811f2068932cf'>
<iq to='intive.com' type='set' id='reg2' xmlns='jabber:client'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
<username>test_auto</username>
<password>test_auto</password>
</query>
</iq>
</body>
```

I get:

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="bla.com" to="test1@bla.com/29309356411303308653389982" id="reg2" type="error">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
<username>test_auto</username>
<password>test_auto</password>
</query><error code="403" type="auth">
<forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>
</iq>
</body>
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, and the solution below doesn't seem to apply to my ejabberd.cfg.

Comment: why downvote as off topic? its i fine question related to programming. Upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, I need to change

```
 {access, register}
```

to

```
 {access_from, register}
```

In order to allow an admin to register a new user

Comment: This was correct solution for me too.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem which was resolved by commenting out the {ip_access, .. section of {mod_register, [... in the ejabberd.cfg file.

Comment: and changing access to access_from did the job for me